# How do I pass a constructor parameter to another object?

Tags: java, oop, constructor

I hope this illustration will make my question clear:

```
class someThread extends Thread{
        private int num;
        public Testing tobj = new Testing(num); //How can I pass the value from the constructor here? 

        public someThread(int num){ 
            this.num=num;
        }

        void someMethod(){
            someThread st = new someThread(num);
            st.tobj.print(); //so that I can do this
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Please don't extend Thread it's a bad idea.  If you want to use a constructor parameter, initialise in the constructor.

Answer (score 6):

For one thing, having a public field is a bad idea to start with IMO. (Your names aren't ideal either...)

All you need to do is initialize it *in the constructor* instead of inline:

```
private int num;
private final Testing tobj;

public someThread(int num) {
    this.num = num;
    tobj = new Testing(num);
}
```

(You don't have to make it final - I just prefer to make variables final when I can...)

Of course, if you don't need `num` for anything else, you don't need it as a field at all:

```
private final Testing tobj;

public someThread(int num) {
    tobj = new Testing(num);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just initialize your object in the constructor ??

```
 public Testing tobj ; //How can I pass the value from the constructor here? 

        public someThread(int num){ 
            this.num=num;
            tobj  = new Testing(this.num);
        }
```